# AI Tech Filtering Experiences That May Cause Trauma

Tags: artificial-intelligence, mind-control

Would it be possible for AI technology to monitor brain activity and filter experiences that may cause trauma in the future? Somehow blocking the memory so it doesn't have any effect on your mental health?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi James. Can you define how it would filter it? Also it can be very troublesome to get the right data. From the top of my head trauma, love and obsession all share remarkably similar repeating patterns in the brain. Could you give some guidelines on how you would select this?

Comment: Welcome James. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] an and when for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: As the author of your fictional world, then you're free to handwave this in. If you're asking if it is possible in the real world, then I'd point out that we have no AI, and astonishingly poor understanding of memories. What exactly is the basis of your question?

Comment: You need to consider that blocking memories can lead to psychological trauma as well. Also, Starfish Prime has a good point: Modern knowledge and technology are not at the level where we can extrapolate from them to answer your question. It might be a better idea to describe your envisioned technology design and then ask whether it is feasible.

Comment: You need to watch Black Mirror. Don't binge it though, it's sort of depressing.

Comment: No need for AI when we have [soma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_New_World). (And Huxley's *Brave New World* is usually considered a dystopian novel.)

Answer (score 0):

## Such a thing *can* be done ...

Let's start by speaking of [beta blockers such as propranolol used in PTSD](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4818733/).  These drugs are used to prevent the person "learning" an excessively traumatic response to a specific incident, and are more effective if given soon after the incident than if given during the recollection of the fearful circumstance.  But not necessarily *in*effective.

Now a memories of a fearful event are still subject to consolidation, being remembered and rewritten over time, and chronic propranolol is still not *useless*.  But we should look deeper into what fear *is*.  Notably, you would think that fear is associated with stress hormones, such as cortisol - yet PTSD patients have [less cortisol](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6952249/) while administering cortisol is said to [reduce PTSD memory](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18761097/)  But if you go one step back to ACTH, there is a study out there (see [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8509551/)) linking more ACTH to PTSD.  Maybe fear is its own antidote, at least in some people - the hypothalamus of the brain, afraid, leads to adrenal-fueled ruggedness.

But let's also speak of reflexes, and the *other* adrenal response, in the medulla, namely adrenaline.  What triggers a sympathetic fight-or-flight response, and all the heart rate variations and so on that B.F. Skinner could have told us were the nature of fear itself?  Going back to Pavlov, a person or a dog can be trained to be afraid at a very reflexive level, with a stimulus leading directly to a reaction.

Introducing:  the [Tranquila](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgSPE22hvSY).  A simple device, no AI required.  Whenever the user starts producing ACTH, it releases extra cortisol, and propranolol, and whatever random tranks were on the pharmacy shelf that day.  Fear -> Unfear, easy peasy.  Whatever we encounter, good or bad, we're OK with it.

But where the AI?  Well, sometimes the user is *supposed* to be afraid.  They might be wounded, or contemplate self-harm, or worse ... they might blaspheme the Religion, or the Leader, or think or say things they ought not.  So the AI turns them up and turns them down, keeps them in abject terror where all good citizens are supposed to be, while relaxing them against the occasional stress that comes with war against those treacherous Eurasians.